# how to change url in wordpress using htaccess menualy without using parmalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have generated this type url in my web site.

```
 http://example.com/?page_id=30
```

Change in to like this type

```
  http://example.com/features/
```

So, how can i change it in wordpress htaccess using. 
This web site is working in to local host perfectly good.But not live.

Comment: Why you want to do using .htacess where wordpress admin panle is providing easy permalink structure change option.

Comment: but not working. I got Error 404

Comment: Please check my answer..

Comment: yes i have use parmalinks but i have show error 404 using post name

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with some 301 redirects in your .htaccess. It could look like:

```
# Only do rewriting if the needed Module is available
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Change this path, if your installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
RewriteBase /

#Following Block for every page you want to redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=30$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/features/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=31$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/features-too/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=32$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/features-again/? [R=301,L]

# and so on... 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you might getting 404 error after change permalink structure from wordpress admin because I think you are missing mod_rewrite in .htaccess ,

Please add following code in your root .htaccess file and then change permalink from admin panel :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If you have already added above code even though getting error then do below setting :

1 - Go to apache\conf\httpd.conf file

2 - Find for line #rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

3 - Remove # from above line , Save file and restart your server.

I am sure it will work.

Comment: can you please contact your server provider to enable mod_rewrite , then it will work automatically. Because to support above code mod_rewrite should be enable from server.

Comment: may be possible. I will try

Comment: Did you contact your server provider?

Comment: and database is all good. Localhost site is running properly in my computer.

Comment: Can you create one php page and call function `phpinfo();` , open that page in browser and see status for mod_rewrite.